# Azure MS Team integration with Azure DevOps Taskboard only showing Issues, where are my work items?

Tags: azure, microsoft-teams, tfs-workitem, issue-tracking, azure-boards

Azure boards MS Team integration. Only showing Issues or Epics, where are my work items?

I added a tab into a Team channel, and I can see Issues, but there is not option for showing the Work Item field?
On the Azure Boards website I see both fields: Issues and Work items.

[Here is no Work Item field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mo97I.png)

[This is the website showing both types at once](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BE9p.png)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you are not able to see work item field.

If you need to see work item field,
you need to connect to a project and not just a repository.

- From the connect to a Project dialog.
- Use CTRL-Shift to select your options and then choose Connect.

The new Work Items experience is available when you connect to a Azure Repos Git repository.
For further reading please follow the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/view-add-work-items?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser).

Comment: He is asking an answer for Teams integration with DevOps. It seems only Epics and issues can be listed in the taskboard.

Comment: I edited the original post with two pictures showing what I mean, thank you for your help :) <3 https://stackoverflow.com/q/67772751/16084774

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up and manage subscriptions for creating and updating work items. You can create subscriptions to monitor work items at any time using the `@azure boards subscriptions` command.
Please go through the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/integrations/boards-teams?view=azure-devops) for more info.

Comment: I edited the original post with two pictures showing what I mean, thank you for your help :) <3 https://stackoverflow.com/q/67772751/16084774

Answer (score 0):

wow I can believe after almost a year nobody replied you. You can set it up in the Organization Settings > Boards > Settings then you can see the process selected. e.g Agile, Basic (what you mentioned) Scrum, etc.

I hope helped someone after this.